# How to merge 5 identical datasets into one dataset and then find the sum of the values

Tags: sas

I have multiple identical excel reports where the headings and format for each report are identical. This is a yearly report that's filled out so the only thing that changes is the numerical values inside of the report boxes.

I want to turn multiple years of data into just one report so that there is a single dataset for the results of the past 5 years. I was wondering how i would go about doing this, where the dataset format is the same but all 5 years worth of data will be added together into this one dataset. For example the numerical vales of cell A2 for each year would be added together and would be present in the final report in cell A2.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm sure this is doable, but can you please post some example code and mock data so we can help understand how best to help out?

Comment: Is SAS used to create the original reports ?  What kind of values are in the cell above (A1) and the cells below (A3:A*n*)?  Are the report boxes named ranges?  How would you know if a cell, say C4, was either a report box or not?

Answer (score 0):

1. Import all the data
2. Depending on the data you will either merge (place side by side) or append (place one on top of the other) the inputted data sets. I'm guessing you want the latter.

Some things to keep in mind - Excel doesn't enforce variable types so if SAS thinks any cell in a column is a character it imports it as a character. So when stacking the data you can often get into a type issue.

Also, you can specify a RANGE on PROC IMPORT to import only the data but if your 'table' has a lot of custom formatting it may be hard to read in and restructure.

Answer (score 0):

If the structure of the datasets are as follows:

```
       Var1 Var2 Var3 ... VarN
Obs1
Obs2
Obs3
.
.
.
ObsN
```

And you just want to put them on top of each other then its simply:

```
Data want;
Set have1 have2 have3 ... haveN;
run;
```